# Binding an NSTreeController to an NSOutlineView in code

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa

I'm looking to bind an `NSTreeController`, which in turn is bound to an array, to an `NSOutlineView`:

```
treeController.bind(NSContentArrayBinding,
    toObject: viewModel,
    withKeyPath: "items",
    options: nil)

outlineView.bind(NSContentBinding,
    toObject: treeController,
    withKeyPath: "arrangedObjects",
    options: nil)

outlineView.bind(NSSortDescriptorsBinding,
    toObject: treeController,
    withKeyPath: "sortDescriptors",
    options: nil)

outlineView.bind(NSSortDescriptorsBinding,
    toObject: treeController,
    withKeyPath: "selectionIndexPaths",
    options: nil)
```

`items` in `viewModel` contains an object which in turn has its own array of children.

However, when doing the above binding, nothing shows in the UI. I've also tried adding a column:

```
let column = NSTableColumn(identifier: "0")

column.bind(NSValueBinding,
    toObject: treeController,
    withKeyPath: "arrangedObjects.displayName"),
    options: nil)

outlineView.addTableColumn(column)
```

But to no avail, I still don't get any results rendered in the UI.

What am I missing to make the binding work? The NSOutlineView renders as expected, just with no items in.

*(Feel free to answer in Objective-C, I'm not picky on language choice)*

Comment: Did you set the `childrenKeyPath` of the tree controller? If so, to what?

Comment: I didn't set `childrenKeyPath` to anything, no.

Comment: You need to. Otherwise, the tree controller can't understand the data structure that it's pointed to. The `childrenKeyPath` should be the key path, relative to an element of the `items` array, that gives an array of that element's children.

Comment: Ah, perfect. You should add that as a answer. I'm surprised that no items was rendered when `childrenKeyPath` wasn't set. Even setting it to a invalid value, makes the parent items start rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `childrenKeyPath` of the tree controller. Otherwise, the tree controller can't understand the data structure that it's pointed to. The `childrenKeyPath` should be the key path, relative to an element of the `items` array, that gives an array of that element's children.